# Nativescript. nativescript-local-notifications always creates two notifications

Tags: firebase, notifications, nativescript

I use nativescript-local-notifications and nativescript-plugin-firebase.

I want to create notification each time, when server send me a message. Here is code:

```
firebase.init({
        storageBucket: 'gs://shao-by-partner-firebase.appspot.com',
        persist: true, // optional, default false


        onPushTokenReceivedCallback: function (token) {
            Config.device_token = token;
            console.log("Firebase plugin received a push token: " + token);
        },
        onMessageReceivedCallback: function (message) {
                  LocalNotifications.schedule([{
                        id: 1,
                        title: 'The title',
                        body: 'Recurs every minute until cancelled',
                        ticker: 'The ticker',
                        badge: 1,
                        smallIcon: 'res://heart.png'
                      }]).then(
                          function() {
                            console.log("Notification scheduled");
                          },
                          function(error) {
                            console.log("scheduling error: " + error);
                          }
                      )
        }
    }).then(
        function (result) {
            console.log("Firebase is ready");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
        }
    );
}
```

But always created two notifications instead of one. And first notification is empty. And second notification is that I created. What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but you are using two plugins to handle remote notifications?

`nativescript-plugin-firebase` already handles notifications for you, I don't think you need the local notifications plugin.

In the example you posted, you are receiving the original notification (the blank one), pluss the local one that you create in the `onMessageReceivedCallback`.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md#handling-a-notification

Comment: May be you are right, but when I deleting LocalNotifications.schedule(...) both notifications don't created.

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right, sorry for so long answer

Answer (score 0):

The is nothing in your onMessageReceived to determine if the message had any content.
You can try adding a conditional statement to your onMessageReceived function and check if the message has content. eg

```
if (message.title){
   //send local notification
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Each time, when I create LocalNotification, I delete notification with id 0:
     LocalNotifications.cancel (0);
But I still don't know,where it comes from.